# r rvest scraping multiple urls with multiple websites and missing values in some nodes

Tags: r, web-scraping, web-crawler, screen-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape employee reviews from kununu. The kununu site has two specific features that need to be taken care of: 1. only the first 10 reviews per company are shown on the first site and 2. not all items I want to collect are present for each review (missing values in some nodes).

My code works fine for one company. But I do not get it to work for a list of urls (e.g. url <- c("https://www.kununu.com/de/novartis-pharma/kommentare", "https://www.kununu.com/de/merckaa/kommentare")

I tried many different approaches - but nothing worked so far - maybe one of you knows the trick. Thank you all very much in advance!

My working code (one company) goes like this:

```
url <- "https://www.kununu.com/de/novartis-pharma/kommentare" 

num_of_reviews <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(".company-profile-subnav .active .title-number") %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  html_text()

# round up to nearest 10s
num_of_reviews_rounded <- num_of_reviews %>%
  as.numeric() %>%
  round_any(10, f = ceiling)

pages <- 1 : (num_of_reviews_rounded / 10)

get_reviews <- function(url){
  reviews <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(".review-content")

  quote <- reviews %>%
    lapply(.%>% html_nodes(".review-title a") %>%
             html_text() %>% ifelse(identical(., character(0)), NA, .)) %>% unlist

  date <- reviews %>%
    lapply(.%>% html_nodes(".hidden+ span") %>%
             html_text() %>% ifelse(identical(., character(0)), NA, .)) %>% unlist

  rating_image <- reviews %>%
    lapply(.%>% html_nodes(".review-ratings .rating-group:nth-child(13) .rating-badge") %>%
             html_text() %>% ifelse(identical(., character(0)), NA, .)) %>% unlist

  statement <- reviews %>%
    lapply(.%>% html_nodes(".col-sm-10 > div:nth-child(1)") %>%
             html_text() %>% ifelse(identical(., character(0)), NA, .)) %>% unlist


  a<-data.frame(quote, date, rating_image, statement,
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  return(a)
}

list_of_dfs <- lapply(pages, function(x)get_reviews(paste0(url,"/",x)))
dfshort <- do.call(rbind, list_of_dfs)

str(dfshort)
```

Comment: Be careful if they decide to enforce #5 https://www.kununu.com/us/terms (that's more of a helpful warning to others since it's unlikely to deter you from stealing content).

Comment: Where is your call for multiple urls and what is the error you're getting? You could do all of it in one single step - the function gets the number of reviews and then scrapes over all the pages to get the comments and returns it all as a list. I dot it routinely for an internal intranet page. Anyway, like @hrbrmstr mentioned, I'd be careful of scraping content like this - might land you in trouble.

Comment: Thank you! I tried different approaches (e.g. 
    url <- c("https://www.kununu.com/de/novartis-pharma/kommentare", "https://www.kununu.com/de/merckaa/kommentare")

Then, I tried to use either "lapply" or "for" to create a loop - but for some reason it did not work. I think that one problem is the code for dealing with missing values ( lapply(.%>% html_nodes(".review-title a") %>%
             html_text() %>% ifelse(identical(., character(0)), NA, .)) %>% unlist)

Comment: most of the time when trying to adapt the code I got the error message "Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"

Comment: do you have a specific idea how to advance the code so that I can automate it for a list of websites?